# Partner lied on visit visa application. Now married, spouse visa refused. Appealing but can he be banned?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

Partner lied on previous visit visa application. We are now married, but his spouse visa was refused as they don't believe we have been together since 2012. We are appealing but can he be banned due to previous conduct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78294/discussion-on-question-by-victoria-partner-lied-on-visit-visa-application-now-m).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, potentially. It depends on the wording of the refusal. Once a deception is on record, any future application may also be refused (for up to 10 years, I believe) under paragraph 320(7B) of the immigration rules.

See: [General Grounds for Refusal](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/674002/GGFR-Section-5-v29.0EXT.PDF)

Comment: That will not be the case if the spouse (the sponsor) in an EU citizen.

Comment: Can I please ask, do you know that for sure? We have appeal in November and I am going to represent myself. Any help/advice would be most gratefully received :)

Comment: What was the kind of visa application that your spouse lied on?

Comment: @Victoria visas for non-EU family members is a right and your spouse can't be banned because of it. As I understand they didn't refuse the spouse visa to your spouse because of the previous ban but it's because they suspect your marriage is not genuine. That happens a lot even to some people who never had a previous ban. If you can prove that your marriage is genuine then it's more likely that you win the appeal.

Comment: Thank you again Sayed for taking the time to reply, its really appreciated. Before we married, my husband lied on his visitor visa application to come and see me as so many people told him that he would be refused as not enough links to go return to home country. A lawyer in Lagos also told him the same thing so he stupidly said that he was married and used his brothers marriage certificate as evidence :(  Of course I was furious when I found out and it nearly broke us up.

Comment: We then got married and applied for spouse visa. We told the whole truth but it seems that the application was not read properly as they didnt say anything about lies or deception, but refused as they dont believe that we have been together since 2012.

Comment: I am still very worried that when I go to the appeal, that they will say that he has now been banned for 10years due to his deception. This whole thing has made me very ill and I cant take much more of the stress. Do you know that what you are saying is absolutely correct? Is there somewhere that I can read more? I scour the internet most days but havent found out this answer specifically. Thank you again for your kindness. Victoria :)